How to parallelize a Jupyter notebook processing?
I'm a researcher and use Jupyter notebooks to study concepts.
However, once it's done, I need to parallelize the Jupyter notebook processing, to run for multiple different inputs
input_variable_1 = ...
input_variable_2 = ...

In the Jupyter notebook, most of the code was written in functions. However, there are cases where the Python objects, such as
variable_01                   # constants
variable_02                   # constants
list_01                       # simple, well defined list
list_02 = fun_01()  
list_03 = fun_02(variable_01) 

were used as the global variables within the parameters.
fun_03()                      # internally dependent on variable_01

I learned that variables, declared as the global, could be defined locally within a module.
I want to know if there is any good way to parallelize the Jupyter notebook and obtain the results.
result_fun(input_variable_1 ,input_variable_2)

The code itself was written with some programming practices and can be changed to Python module very easily, but the issue is the Jupyter notebook might still be updated and each update meant I need to reconvene the process to change it from a Jupyter notebook to a Python module.
I heard about nbconvert and import_ipynb packages, but not sure what's the best approach. The parallelization is with respect to process not threads.
How to parallelize the Jupyter notebook?

Large research & academia infrastructures spent decades on promoting Jupyter-notebooks for rapid-prototyping & experimentation. Also developed HPC-backends, grids, tools as user-facing computing ecosystem for then performing high performance computing. Ad-hoc grids, configured from / for Jupyter notebooks (managed) [tag:distributed-computing] are an entry-level technology, HPC-backends the top-level, for doing what you asked for. Do not expect generic SO community to address this indepth - details depend on your research ecosystem infrastructure. Do not hesitate ask Tech ppl at your DataCentre

Just a not quite complete solution, I realized an almost trivial way, but quick way to do it.

use if __name__ == "__main__": practice for proper maintenance.

export the Jupyter notebook to .py file in raw.

select the entire script.

press tab.

put def parallel_process(input_variable_1, input_variable_2) at the top of it.

process pool


It should cost no more than few seconds for each of the further maintenance.
